# Show Totals for MTD

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three columns in my table (Market): Salesman, Sales and Week. I want to be able to tally the total for MTD (month to date). In my case, I want to be able to provide the data from the table from 11-18-2016 to 12-18-2016. I do not know how to formulate the MTD column in my table. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
select * from Market:

Salesman             Sales                    Week
Joe                   40                     12-18-2016
Mike                  27                     12-11-2016 
Todd                  29                     12-04-2016
Robert                44                     11-27-2016
Tony                  15                     11-20-2016
Morgan                60                     11-13-2016
Edwin                 25                     11-06-2016 
Josh                  19                     10-30-2016
Travis                24                     10-23-2016
Wade                  35                     10-16-2016
```

The result I require:

```
Select Salesman, Sales as 'This Week', (some formula) as 'MTD' from Market
where Week = '12-18-2016'

Salesman             This Week                  MTD
Joe                    40                       40
Mike                    0                       27
Todd                    0                       29
Robert                  0                       44
Tony                    0                       15
```

Comment: Does anyone have headway on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using window functions.  For a single week, this should do:

```
select m.*
from (Select Salesman, Sales as "This Week",
             sum(Sales) over (partition by SalesMan, date_trunc('month', week)
                              order by week) as MTD
      from Market m
     ) m
where Week = '2016-12-18';  -- assumes that the date is stored in a native date/time format
```

The `order by` in the `over` clause is only needed to support weeks that are not the latest week.

Comment: Although it does not return an error, it returns empty fields.

Comment: @PLearner . . . This does assume that `week` is a date/time column (i.e. not stored as a string).